# How to show result in "value input" and not in "ID input"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to load the result into the "value" of the field and not the ID as below, how could I do this? The way I'm doing is not saving in the database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let total = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]').forEach(el=>total+=+el.value);
document.querySelector('#total').value = total;
console.log(total);
</script>
```

Comment: You're already setting the result to the value of #total - `querySelector('#` just lets you select the element, it doesn't change its ID or anything. What database are you referring to? You haven't posted anything about what it is or how to access it in your code.

Comment: change `total+=+el.value` to `total+=el.value`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I know this but I want to insert the value into "value"

Comment: @Kenny does not work :(

Comment: @J.Z can you create a working example, so that we can figure ouit what is going wrong